# Publsih action in Open Graph giving error

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am using Post action in Open graph using the below code, but getting the error message "[Object Object]"

What might be the problem???, i followed all the step by step guidance to  publish an action from this URL
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#publish

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function postArticle() {
           FB.api(
        '/me/ICONSolutions-test:Read',
        'post',
        { Article: 'http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.html' },
        function (response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert(response.error);
            } else {
                alert('Successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
            }
        });
       }
  </script>

<input type="button" value="POST" onclick="postArticle()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're `alert()`-ing an object which has no toString method that gives a readable representation of the object.

Dump the value to the console instead, `console.log(response)` – and have a look at it in Firebug or a similar debugging tool that implements console.

Comment: CBroe, i get to see the following : code
 2500
 
message
 "Unknown path components: /ICONSolutions-test:Read"
 
type
 "OAuthException"